# Existence of “Larger” Projection?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $H$ is a separable Hilbert space. If $P,Q$ are two finite dimension orthonormal projection, is there a finite dimension orthonormal projection $L$, st:

$$
L(H)\supset P(H), L(H)\supset Q(H)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $L$ to be the orthogonal projection onto the finite dimensional subspace $P(H)+Q(H)$.